# IDisposable.Dispose is not available when trying to use a class in other assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have a data access class library called DataWare. Inside I have the context class that is defined this way:

```
namespace DataWare
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class GestionCasinoEntities : DbContext
    {
        public GestionCasinoEntities()
            : base("name=GestionCasinoEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Auditoria> Auditoria { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CentroCosto> CentroCosto { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contingencia> Contingencia { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Departamento> Departamento { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Empresa> Empresa { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Equipo> Equipo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Funcionario> Funcionario { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GrupoParametro> GrupoParametro { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GrupoServicio> GrupoServicio { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Marcacion> Marcacion { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Modulo> Modulo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pais> Pais { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Parametro> Parametro { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Semana> Semana { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Servicio> Servicio { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Turno> Turno { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UbicacionEquipo> UbicacionEquipo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to use that class from other assembly, only DbSet properties are available, not Dispose method. So, I cannot do something like this:

```
            using (GestionCasinoEntities db = new GestionCasinoEntities())
            {
            }
```

What may it be happening here?

If inside the GestionCasinoEntities code I write this.Dispose, intellisense shows it is available, however, when I try to do the same with db.Dispose in the other assembly, Dispose is not available. Maybe some reference is missing.

Comment: Is `GestionCasinoEntities` class defined in a different assembly than the one trying to use it? If that's the case, you'll also need to add a reference EntityFramework.dll to the referring project, thou the compiler should have warned you about that already.

Comment: IntelliSense is not a compiler.  Hit Build > Build once in a while to see your mistakes, you'll now be reminded that you have a missing reference.

Comment: Thanks... unreferenced EntityFramework.dll was the problem, so I have used Nuget to add it to the project and the problem was solved.

Comment: @Fede: If you want, you can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posting `Fede`'s comment as a community wiki answer. Please delete, if `Fede` posts his own answer.*

Fede said:

> Is `GestionCasinoEntities` class defined in a different assembly than the one trying to use it? If that's the case, ***you'll also need to add a reference `EntityFramework.dll` to the referring project***, though the compiler should have warned you about that already.